# Wordpress Custom Plugin Installable code

Tags: wordpress

I have created my own custom plugin and when i just paste it in my plugin folder its working fine. now i wanted to make it installable so if anyone try to install in their project so they can install it with the given plugin upload menu in admin panel.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have the same quetion.. haw can we make a custom plugin installable.. so any one go to install plugin page in wordpress and upload the zip and plugin should show in plugins list..

Answer (score 0):

Copy the plugin_file_name.php in the folder /wp-content/plugins and its ready to work. But is better Create a folder and put in file.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple process to make your plugin installable. Just register 3 hooks in your plugin :

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'your_activation_function_name');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'your_deactivate_function_name');
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'your_delete_function_name');
```

In `your_delete_function_name` function, please add code to remove the **db changes** you made and also code to **remove your plugin directory**.

Now just zip the folder of your custom plugin folder and its ready to be installed in any wordpress site. It worked for me as i am working in wordpress 4.6.